# Get key/value pair from HTML Storage

Tags: html, regex, xml, bash, sed

I would like to extract all the key and value pairs from a HTML storage format text file. I need to get all the values of the userkey key and save them.
Storage format looks like this for example:

```
ame="profile-picture" ac:schema-version="1"><ac:parameter ac:name="User"><ri:user ri:userkey="2c9289304dbbc5b3014dbd91f1070003" /></ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></td><td><ac:link><ri:user ri:userkey="2c9289304dbbc5b3014dbd91f1070003" /></ac:link></td><td><p>Framework Team</p></td><td>+ 4 New York 04</td></tr><tr><td colspan="1"><ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="a5a4315a-b070-4af5-bf4b-6785b6ae50e4" ac:name="profile-picture" ac:schema-version="1"><ac:parameter ac:name="User"><ri:user ri:userkey="2c9289304dd05f3e014dd3ed18470027" /></ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></td><td colspan="1"><ac:link><ri:user ri:userkey="2c9289304dd05f3e014dd3ed18470027" /></ac:link></td><td colspan="1">Framework Team</td><td colspan="1">+ 4 New York 02</td></tr><tr><td colspan="1"><ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="a700d77f-0fb0-4288-9a0b-198a35e75f05" ac:name="profile-picture" ac:schema-version="1"><ac:parameter ac:name="User"><ri:user ri:userkey="2c9289304dd5858a014dd74be3a80008" /></ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></td><td colspan="1"><ac:link><ri:user ri:userkey="2c9289304dd5858a014dd74be3a80008" /></ac:link></td><td colspan="1">Framework Team</td><td colspan="1">+ 4 New York 02</td></tr><tr><td colspan="1"><ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="291fc9f1-db1c-48af-8897-3ac294b6e608" ac:name="profile-picture" ac:schema-version="1"><ac:parameter ac:name="User"><ri:user ri:userkey="2c9289304dd05f3e014dd3e24b1a0021" /></ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></td><td colspan="1"><ac:link><ri:user ri:userkey="2c9289304dd05f3e014dd3e24b1a0021" /></ac:link></td><td colspan="1">Framework Team</td><td colspan="1">+ 4 New York 02</td></tr><tr><td colspan="1"><ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="0c453e0b-f441-408f-8784-7545192d8d0a" ac:name="profile-picture" ac:schema-version="1"><ac:parameter ac:name="User"><ri:user ri:userkey="2c9289304dd5858a014dd751a512000b" /></ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></td><td colspan="1"><ac:link><ri:user ri:userkey="2c9289304dd5858a014dd751a512000b" /><ac:plain-text-link-body><![CDATA[Stephan]]></ac:plain-text-link-body></ac:link><ac:link><ri:user ri:userkey="2c9289304dd5858a014dd751a512000b" /><ac:plain-text-link-body><![CDATA[ Ngoie Kapenda]]></ac:plain-text-link-body></ac:link></td><td colspan="1">Framework Team</td><td colspan="1">+ 4 New York 02</td></tr><tr><td><ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="518fb9ae-e1e5-4d71-9147-e5e5c6a4ffe2" ac:name="profile-picture" ac:schema-version="1"><ac:parameter ac:name="User"><ri:user ri:userkey="8a45f48d52ae76760152b1dfc49b0019" /></ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></td><td><ac:link><ri:user ri:userkey="8a45f48d52ae76760152b1dfc49b0019" /></ac:link></td><td>Framework Team</td><td>+ 4 New York 04</td></tr><tr><td colspan="1"><ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="bf34bc8c-3803-44b7-a4db-0d0181207103" ac:name="profile-picture" ac:schema-version="1"><ac:parameter ac:name="User"><ri:user ri:userkey="8a45f48d5209ab0601520d2585020014" /></ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></td><td colspan="1"><ac:link><ri:user ri:userkey="8a45f48d5209ab0601520d2585020014" /></ac:link></td><td colspan="1">Framework Team</td><td colspan="1">+ 4 New York 04</td></tr><tr><td colspan="1"><ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="cf90f25b-b5cc-4fd0-8ecb-0ee6d59cc46b" ac:name="profile-picture" ac:schema-version="1"><ac:parameter ac:name="User"><ri:user ri:userkey="8a45f48d5b7394ed015b8594ebf90017" /></ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></td><td colspan="1"><ac:link><ri:user ri:userkey="8a45f48d5b7394ed015b8594ebf90017" /></ac:link></td><td colspan="1"><span>Framework Team</span></td><td colspan="1"><span>+ 4 New York 02</span></td></tr><tr><td colspan="1"><ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="b763a704-a016-47db-b2cd-a49c465e0772" ac:name="profile-picture" ac:schema-version="1"><ac:parameter ac:name="User"><ri:user ri:userkey="8a45f48d4ef532a5014ef855cd06000a" /></ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></td><td colspan="1"><ac:link><ri:user ri:userkey="8a45f48d4ef532a5014ef855cd06000a" /></ac:link></td><td colspan="1">Change Manager</td><td colspan="1">+ 4 New York 04</td></tr><tr><td colspan="1"><ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="b04b7168-01d8-4247-ac54-d61f12bc3d7d" ac:name="profile-picture" ac:schema-version="1"><ac:parameter ac:name="User"><ri:user ri:userkey="8a45f48d59d7cf310159db1df7d70009" /></ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></td><td colspan="1"><ac:link><ri:user ri:userkey="8a45f48d59d7cf310159db1df7d70009" /></ac:link></td><td colspan="1"><span>Data Governance&nbsp;</span></td><td colspan="1"><span>+ 4 New York 08</span></td></tr><tr><td colspan="1"><ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="2c34834f-b6e6-4720-b4b0-960c12681271" ac:name="profile-picture" ac:schema-version="1"><ac:parameter ac:name="User"><ri:user ri:userkey="8a45f48d5bbbae0d015bc807c0850009" /></ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></td><td colspan="1"><ac:link><ri:user ri:userkey="8a45f48d5bbbae0d015bc807c0850009" /></ac:link></td><td colspan="1"><span>Data Governance&nbsp;</span></td><td colspan="1"><span>+ 4 New York 08</span></td></tr></tbody></table></ac:layout-cell></ac:layout-section></ac:layout>
```

I use the following regular expression to get the values:

```
sed -n 's/.*userkey="\(.*\)"/\1/p' | cut -f1 -d ' ' | tr -d '"'
```

But I only get a value back. I would like to get all values. So, what's wrong with this regular expression?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't show us the expected output, so I am only printing the values here, let me know if you have any queries.

```
awk -v RS='[ :]' '/userkey/'  Input_file
```

Also I could see your Input_file is coming into a single line, so this code has been written as per shown Input_file.